# Как сделать подключение с помощью файла ovpn js

Tags: javascript, electron

У меня есть фронт на electorn js, одна кнопка "Подключиться", я искал библиотеки для того, чтобы в код импортировать ovpn файл и организовать подключение, как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению, я не нашел нормального способа подключения, поэтому использовал **child-proces**.

Создал файл **connect.ps1** - расширение для PowerShell.

**connect.ps1**

```
path/to/openvpn.exe --config your_cfg.ovpn
```

**file.js**

```
exec("powershell.exe -ExecutionPulicy Bypass -File windows.ps1", (error, stdout, stderr)
```

пример моей реализации